# I keep seeing "myApp.controllers" or "myApp.modules" in Angular JS. What does this mean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I keep seeing code similar to the following:

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
```

I've seen this in [some](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app) tutorials. I don't understand the significance of the `.controllers` in the module name. I've looked but can't find any information.

When I go into my console and try to access it I get nothing

So I guess my question(s) are:

1. What is the significance of the `.controllers` in `.module("app.controllers")`?
2. Are there other such suffixes that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no significance. You can call your modules what you like.

Comment: So if I start an application using `angular.module('app')`, then `angular.module('app.controllers')` is just completely irrelevant to it?

Comment: Yes. Though it's sensible to group your code into several modules and use `angular.module('oneModule', ['anotherModule'])`.

Comment: So I guess a bit of an explanation as to conventional organization patterns would be awesome. I'm (obviously) new to Angular and I'd like to learn what to expect/what I should be doing in order to be a "good Angular developer"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a single module either. There is nothing I can say about Angular modules that wouldn't apply to modules or packages in any other language.